Configuring a Lambda to act as a Celery Worker
i'm looking for advise on how to proper use a lambda to mimic a worker job, by using the following configuration:
AWS MQ using rabbitMQ as broker.
Lambda with configured Trigger listening on a MQ queue.
A Workflow defined in my celery app with some tasks:
task_01: runs on a celery worker instance.
task_02: runs on lambda, i put then on a specific queue that no other worker listen to.
task_03: runs on a celery worker instance.
    workflow = chain(
        task_01.s(),
        task_02.s(),
        task_03.s()
    )

If i execute task_01, the lambda on task_02 is triggered correctly, but i need to mimic celery code, save the result to the backend and trigger task_03 correctly.
I'm currently using the code below to save the task_02 result, but i need to make some workflow functions like chain, group, chord, to be called.
from celery.worker.request import Request

def handler(event, context):
    message_data = # get the data from the event
    message = {name: 'x', 'headers': message_data_headers)
    r = Request(message, app=app)

    r.execute()
    

i need another logic to call the next task on the chain list.
For a task without a workflow, it works, but i want to know if i can make it work for every scenario.
